# How to capture redirected URL when the connection fails? [Python3]

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I am using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library to capture the redirected URL.
Let me demonstrate this with the following code :

```
import requests
try:
   headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36',}
   response = requests.get('https://www.mooc-list.com/go.php?courseId=3502', timeout=3, headers=headers)
   response.raise_for_status()
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as errh:
    print ("Http Error:",errh)
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as errc:
    print ("Error Connecting:",errc)
except requests.exceptions.Timeout as errt:
    print ("Timeout Error:",errt)  
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
    print ("Oops : Something Else",err)
```

And I get the following output :

> Error Connecting: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='hub0.ecolearning.eu', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /course/smooc-step-by-step-2ed/ (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to hub0.ecolearning.eu timed out. (connect timeout=3)'))

However, when I try to print the URL by executing `print(response.url)`, there's a Name Error as shown

> NameError: name 'response' is not defined

This basically means the `response` object isn't initialised when connection fails therefore I cannot capture the URL history or the redirects.

I don't mind if the connection fails but I would like to extract the URL redirects. Is there any turnaround for this?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we can not open the url which redirect to. We can try to find `Location` from http headers. So i choose to stop auto redirect on `requests`, and build up a new redirector

```
import requests
def Final_location(url):
    try:
        headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36',}
        response = requests.get(url, timeout=3 , allow_redirects=False , headers=headers)
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as errh:
        print ("Http Error:",errh)
        return url
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as errc:
        print ("Error Connecting:",errc)
        return url
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout as errt:
        print ("Timeout Error:",errt)
        return url
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
        print ("Oops : Something Else",err)
        return url

    if response.headers.get("Location"):
        return Final_location(response.headers.get("Location"))
    else:
        return response.url

    #Location = Final_location(response.headers.get("Location")) if response.headers.get("Location") else response.url
    #return Location


print(Final_location('https://www.mooc-list.com/go.php?courseId=3502'))
```

Output:

```
Error Connecting: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='hub0.ecolearning.eu', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /course/smooc-step-by-step-2ed/ (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', timeout('_ssl.c:817: The handshake operation timed out',)))
https://hub0.ecolearning.eu/course/smooc-step-by-step-2ed/#
```

Comment: This is a recursive solution. Isn't?

Answer (score 0):

```
def ReqGet():
    try :
        resp =  requests.get(url, params=params, headers = headers,timeout=3)
        return resp
    except Exception as e 
        return e 

res = ReqGet()    
print(res.request.url)
```

The Error object has the last redirected request , from that request you can take the url